# How to filter out selected records from /etc/hosts file from terminal prompts for ssh command

Tags: bash, ssh, hosts, auto-completion

I have a problem with hints for the ssh command. When I press the tab key, the terminal displays all records from the /etc/host file in prompts. I use add-ons to block spam and advertisements in my browser. These add-ons save their records to /etc/hosts as follows:

```
127.0.0.1 domain
```

e.g.

```
127.0.0.1 ads.xyz.com
```

Is it possible to exclude from the prompts those records which contain e.g. the address 127.0.0.1?

Comment: The offending part would be `_known_hosts_real` in `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`, where it does `compgen -A hostname -P ...`. You could edit that, or you could move from `/etc/hosts` to using `iptables` rules to reject traffic to those hosts.